# I want to change the contacts address when I change an accounts address

Tags: apex, trigger

how is this possible? Can some one wirte a apex class and trigger and explain.

Comment: Could it help, if you used a formula field on the contact object that brings down the value of the parent account's address? In this way all the contacts would automatically have the account's latest address and you can achieve this by point and click. This is only viable if you agree to replace the contact's standard address fields by the new formula field/fields. And also the field in contact wouldn't be editable too, guess that is fine since the contact's address is what the account's address is. Hope this helps

Comment: If your position is not agreeable to the the above suggestion, then a trigger is the only way I guess and @Ruchi has been kind enough to provide the whole algorithm for a bulkified trigger. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, Jane! It's generally considered good practice to include in your question what you've tried up to this point. In my experience here, questions that ask for others to write code without explaining what you've tried tend to get less answers (and less helpful answers). That said, the cross-object formula field suggested by @Stygon is a good suggestion, and I'd recommend using it if possible.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in Process builder and Trailhead will actually walk you through the basics to get you started. Check out the QuickStart Project: [Lightning Process Builde](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/project/quickstart-process-builder)r.

Basic structure:
Change on Account Address fields
Update Contact Records (can filter which contact records as well)

Answer (score 0):

Write a trigger on accounts. Take the list of account ids which are getting updated. Then get the list of all the contacts which are associated to that account. Run over the loop of accounts and contacts and see if (AccounId == ContactId). Inside the loop make Contact.Address = Account.address and add all contacts to a list. Update contact list outside the FOR loop.